# What I need to do, to create a correct route with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I need a route with multiple Parameters.
Like this
URL/name/Thomas/age/22/place/Berlin
also
URL/variablename1/{variable1}/variablename2/{variable2}/variablename3/{variable3}
I need it so that its work to like:
URL/age/22/place/Berlin

```
Route::get('/name/{name}/age/{age}/place/{place}', 'HomeController@social');
```

HomeController:

```
public function social(variablename1=$variable1,variablename2=$variable2,variablename3=$variable3){
//do something
}
```

has there anyone a fast example?

Comment: So have you tried to define your method as `public function social($name, $age, $place)`?

Comment: thats won't work because if the link ist only /22/Berlin ore /Thomas/Berlin its won't work thats will be to easy :D

Comment: That looks like the worst idea ever. Don't do that. What are you trying to do with all those parameters? What's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My code need to know for what the value is that they get in the link

Answer (score 0):

just define your method as

`public function social($name, $age, $place)`

Comment: Its won't work because If one parameter is not there its shows error. and If I put it in route ({name}/{age}/{place}) I need to give all infos. at the moment I make it over $_GET ?kp=10000&lz=12&vz=8

Comment: if you want some parameter to be optional you do like this in your route
`Route::get('/name/{name}/{age?}/{place?}')`

and define your controller like this: `public function social($name, $age = null, $place = null)`

this would make the age and place optional

Comment: thats easy and nice thanks! and how can I solve this if the url only give name and place? also like' /name/Thomas/Berlin' ?

Comment: OK I found a solution with different routes. Thanks you answer helps me to get a answer

Answer (score 0):

First off all, don't name your parameter variable1, variable2,.... It's confusing, use real names.

Secondly, your route seems very weird to me. What is the reason for having so many parameters in your url?

Comment: Please use comments to ask for clarification.

Comment: for a seo friendly url. at the moment its looks like: ?kp=10000&lz=12&vz=8